# how to get lualatexmk to run in \nonstopmode

Tags: luatex, compiling

I use the engine `lualatexmk` to create my documents. This runs the entire pdf-generating-process several times until a stage is reached where an additional run of this process wouldn't change the result anymore. This, at least, is more or less how I believe lualatexmk works.

The content of `lualatex.engine` is:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
export TSBIN="$HOME/Library/TeXShop/bin/tslatexmk"
export LTMKBIN="$HOME/Library/TeXShop/bin/tslatexmk"
export LTMKEDIT="$HOME/Library/TeXShop/bin"
# make sure latexmkrcedit exists in bin
if [ ! -e "${LTMKEDIT}/latexmkrcedit" ] ; then
    cp "${LTMKBIN}/latexmkrcDONTedit" "${LTMKEDIT}/latexmkrcedit"
fi
"${LTMKBIN}"/latexmk -f -pdf -r "${LTMKEDIT}/latexmkrcedit" -r "${TSBIN}/lualatexmkrc" "$1"
```

When I get an error and don't want to care about the error for the moment, I press "r" in the console and it then runs through one process and forgets about all the errors. This mode is called `\nonstopmode`, because it does not stop at each and every error. Since, however, `lualatexmk` runs the document-generating-process several times, I need to press "r" also several times.

My simple question is: How do I have to edit `lualatexmk.engine` to let it run completely in `\nonstopmode`, so that each and every error is ignored for the moment?

Comment: Adding `\nonstopmode` at the beginning of your document would suffice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\...mode` commands can be added directly in the document, and this should work in LuaTeX as well. Therefore adding the following line as the first line of your document should suffice:

```
\nonstopmode
```